# Why Exoplayer does not switch HLS tracks when bandwidth change

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have this simple .m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="English stereo",LANGUAGE="en"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1728000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="audio"
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_360_800000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=628000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=320x180,AUDIO="audio"
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_180_250000.m3u8
```

With simpleExoplayer i load this stream like this :

```
// 1. Create a default TrackSelector
Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector =
    new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

// 2. Create the player
SimpleExoPlayer player =
    ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);

// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
    .createMediaSource(mp4VideoUri);
// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(videoSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

but even on high WIFI internet it's will always select the 2nd track with have a resolution of 320x180 and never switch to the higher track with have a resolution of 640x360.

If i replace DEFAULT_MAX_INITIAL_BITRATE by maxInt then it's will select correctly the 1rt track (640x360) but if in the middle of the playback i cut off the wifi to let the mobile use only the low 3G connection, then it's will never switch to the 2nd track (320x180) and playing will stuck every time

Is also check `MediaCodecUtil.getDecoderInfo("video/avc", false).adaptive` and it's return TRUE

What did i do wrong? does hls work properly in simpleExoPlayer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DefaultBandwidthMeter` is the component to meter network capacity. The `DefaultBandwidthMeter` implements the `BandwidthMeter` and the `TransferListener` interface.

You should only use one instance of DefaultBandwidthMeter and pass it to both, the `AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory` (as a BandwidthMeter) and the `DefaultDataSourceFactory` (as a TransferListener). This way the metering done in the data source takes effect in the track selector.

With your code above the instance you pass to the AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory is not aware of what is metered, which apparently does not work according to what you describe.

Also note that if you create a new `DefaultBandwidthMeter` instance the metering done so far is lost. So you may want to have the `DefaultBandwidthMeter` as static variable or the like to retain the metering from earlier playbacks.

```
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_METER);
TrackSelector trackSelector =
    new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_METER);
```

See also [how the PlayerActivity of the demo application does it](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L106).

Comment: thanks marc, but i just look the source code of DefaultDataSourceFactory (2.6.1) and their is no BANDWIDTH_METER in the list of parameters of the constructor :(

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The DefaultBandwidthMeter implements the TransferListener interface which is passed to the construcotr of the DefaultDataSourceFactory. See https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter.html

Comment: aah ok, I just changed the code and i do now`DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_METER);` but it's change nothing, the player start at 320x180 and never swap to 640x360 :(

Comment: also marc, if you look my original code you will see that i was already using the BandwidthMeter in both new AdaptiveTrackSelection and in DefaultDataSourceFactory ...

Comment: Yes, but you are using two instances there. Looking at the code I'd say it does not compile because you have a duplicate reference 'bandwidthMeter'?

Comment: ooh sorry i badly copy past the code :( no i confirm you in my code i use only one instance in both new AdaptiveTrackSelection and in DefaultDataSourceFactory ...

Comment: Marc, i will look more deeply my code, maybe you are right! do you know if i can use DefaultBandwidthMeter in several simpleExoPlayer *at the same time* ? in this way i can declare a static one and use it in all simpleExoPlayer

Comment: Marc, you are very strong it's was this! very good view thanks !! if you know about the DefaultBandwidthMeter in several simpleExoPlayer at the same time could be great (i open a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535877/can-i-use-defaultbandwidthmeter-in-several-simpleexoplayer-at-the-same-time

Comment: Yes, you can reuse the DefaultBandwidthMeter with several data sources and TrackSelection.Factories. It's your decision how to meter bandwidth. If you stream everything from the same server it makes sense to have one single badnwidth meter for everything. If you know you have two servers, one very slow the other very fast you may want to have separate meterings to get valid measurements and results.

Comment: thanks marc, but to not have any confusion, we agree to say at the same time ? I have 2 simpleExoPlayer instance that are both playing a video at the same time and on different thread, so both of them can use the same DefaultBandwidthMeter without any trouble ?

Comment: Look at the code here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/deb9b301b2c7ef66fdd7d8a3e58298a79ba9c619/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter.java  Everything is synchronized.

Comment: Thanks a lot marc !

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was not switching track when bandwidth change, So I have replaced the `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory` to `OkHttpDataSourceFactory` and added dependency:

here is code snippets:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.12.1'

val httpCallFactory = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .writeTimeout(httpWriteTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(httpReadTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(httpConnectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()
        val dataSourceFactory = OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
            httpCallFactory,
            userAgent,
            transferListener
        )

        /* val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
             userAgent,
             transferListener,
             DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
             DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
             true
         )*/
        val mediaSource: MediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(url), dataSourceFactory)
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource, resetPosition)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
```